# How can I combine the results of two separate WS calls in Play framework?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I have a controller method which sends two web service requests at the same time, I immediately return a promise for both of them. Now what I want to do is combine the results of the two web service calls into a single result returned to the user. The code I have so far is:

```
 public static Promise<Result> search(String searchTerms) {
    final Promise<List<SearchResult>> result1 = webserviceOne(searchTerms);
    final Promise<List<SearchResult>> result2 = webserviceTwo(searchTerms);

    return result1.flatMap(
            new Function<Promise<List<SearchResult>>, Promise<Result>>() {
                public Promise<Result> apply(Promise<List<SearchResult>> res1) {
                    return result2.flatMap(
                        new Function<Promise<List<SearchResult>>, Result>() {
                            public Result apply(Promise<List<SearchResult>> res2) {
                                //TODO: Here I want to combine the two lists of results and return a JSON response
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
    );
}
```

How do I do this? I'm finding it really hard to find decent documentation for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
 public static Promise<Result> search(String searchTerms) {
    final Promise<List<SearchResult>> result1 = webserviceOne(searchTerms);
    final Promise<List<SearchResult>> result2 = webserviceTwo(searchTerms);

    return result1.flatMap(
            new Function<Promise<List<SearchResult>>, Promise<Result>>() {
                public Promise<Result> apply(List<SearchResult> res1) {
                    return result2.flatMap(
                        new Function<Promise<List<SearchResult>>, Result>() {
                            public Result apply(List<SearchResult> res2) {
                                List<SearchResult> newList = new ArrayList<SearchResult>(res1);
                                newList.addAll(res2);
                                return ok(toJson(newList));
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public Zone buildZone(final GeoPoint center, final int distance) {
    Promise<List<Street>> streetPromise = Promise.promise(
            new Function0<List<Street>>() {
                public List<Street> apply() {
                    return streetRepository.findByLocation(center.getGeom(), distance);
                }
            }
    );

    Promise<List<Place>> placePromise = Promise.promise(
            new Function0<List<Place>>() {
                public List<Place> apply() {
                    return placeService.findByLocation(center, distance);
                }
            }
    );

    Promise<Zone> result = Promise.sequence(streetPromise, placePromise).map(
            new Function<List<List<? extends Object>>, Zone>() {
                @Override
                public Zone apply(List<List<? extends Object>> lists) throws Throwable {
                    return new Zone((List<Street>) lists.get(0), (List<Place>) lists.get(1));
                }
            }
    );

    return result.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```